# Sending a notification on window close

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I have a web application where I'm trying to send a notification to a server when the window gets closed. So far the best way I've found has been to use synchronous xhr in the onunload (as async is unreliable). Here's the code at the moment:

```
    window.onunload = function() {
      var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
      req.open('GET', '/api/v1/' + id + '/close?resource=' + JSON.stringify(resource), false);
      req.setRequestHeader('Authorization', localStorage.token);
      req.send();
    }
```

The only problem is when they reload the page, the page freezes for a bit (which I think is due to the xhr). Is there a better way to send notifications to the server when a window is closed?

Answer (score 6):

I think better solution is use `Navigator.sendBeacon` for new browsers - Chrome, Opera and Firefox - because is asynchronous and browser give you promise that will send the request.

This method addresses the needs of analytics and diagnostics code that typically attempt to send data to a web server prior to the unloading of the document.

More you can find here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/sendBeacon

Polyfill: https://github.com/miguelmota/Navigator.sendBeacon

Comment: Interesting that the polyfill is very similar to the code OP posted, i.e., a synchronous request. Yet, OP would still need to call it on the beforeunload event.

Comment: The problem with navigator.sendbeacon is, like you said, it works on new browsers. It doesn't seem to be supported on IE.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the `beforeunload` event. The `unload` event actually happens when the user comes back to the page (since the event can't fire when the webpage is closed, nor before they close the tab since the document hasn't unloaded yet).

Also an additional useful tip is to encode your JSON in URL compatible format: `encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(resource))`.

See here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/beforeunload

Comment: I initially had it as beforeunload, but it seems that XHR requests sent in the beforeunload are not reliable if they're asynchronous (even if I'm not counting on a return value), and contain the same problem as onunload if synchronous, in that refreshing the page freezes everything.